# How to timeout in DOORS DXL?

Tags: ibm-doors

The want the execution to stop for example 5 seconds and then resume execution. the code below seems to be fine but it's not working. It executes directl, it doesn't wait. Can please someone help?

```
sleep_(50) 
string out=""
print win32SystemWait_("cmd.exe /C echo hallo", out, -1)
print "Output :" out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found an answer my code is correct. 
The thing is void sleep_(int milliseconds)